# PHP function checkInfo dynamic, doesn't work

Tags: php, oop, pdo

**I want to check if there's a row with a specific value in a specific column.**

I will check many columns, so I decided to create a function, for everything instead of creating a function `specific` for each thing.

```
    public function checkInfo($column, $parm)
    {
        $this->check = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM recoveries WHERE :column = :parm");
        $this->check->execute(array( ":column" => $column, ":parm" => $parm ));

        if ($this->check->rowCount())
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new exception ("Could not find recovery ".$parm.", ".$column."");
        }
    }
```

**Variable column:** The column name.

**Variable parm:** The parm name (Whatever the user posted in the form).

*And that's how I check if its row count:*

```
    $column = 'recovery_email'; 
    try
    {
        $recover->checkInfo('recovery_email', $_POST['email']);
        echo
        '
            <form action="check.php" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="id">
                <button type="submit" class="btn">Continue</button>
            </form>
        ';
    }
    catch (Exception $t)
    {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-error">'.$t->getMessage().', <a href="check.php">Go back</a></div>';
    }
```

**Result:**

```
 Could not find recovery
```

- The column names are correct.
- And the Parm is correct (Took it from the database).

**Problem:**

I am putting the correct information, yet it giving me an error that could not find the row.

**Question**

*Why is it happening?*

**How can I fix this?**

Comment: Duplicate of [Can I use a PDO prepared statement to bind an identifier (a table or field name) or a syntax keyword?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990857/reference-frequently-asked-questions-about-pdo#15991422)

Comment: @Your Common Sense Oh, so I have to escape it myself? '".$column."' ?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind column names. Bound parameters work only with values.

But even if you could - even a syntactically valid column name would produce an SQL error if the column didn't exist in your table.

- First, check if the column exists *and is allowed to be queried*. There are many ways to do this - the simplest is to use the [`in_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function.
- Then insert column name into your SQL statement via string concatenation (or interpolation), and bind only column value.

Your method would look like this:

```
public function checkInfo($column, $parm)
{
    if(!in_array($column, array('recovery_email', 'my_column2', 'my_column3')))
    {
        throw new exception ("Unknown column: ".$column);
    }

    $this->check = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM recoveries WHERE $column = :parm");
    $this->check->execute(array( ":parm" => $parm ));

    // ... 
}
```